# How to copy file from C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

My C#.Net windows Application connects to a SQLServer2005 database and implements database backup functionality.

In my Application,

I try to perform a file copy like this:

```
<!-- language:lang-csharp -->
File.Copy(Application.StartupPath + "\\dbSTK.mdf",  "D:\\dbSTK123.mdf",true);
```

but it throws an exception with the following message:

```
" The Process cannot Access the File, because it is being use by another Process"
```

How can I copy the db file which is already in use?

Comment: Is it still open in the database if so close the existing connection and try. If the file which you are trying to copy is still opened this will issue arise.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot copy mdf file while SqlServer is running. Just temporary shut SqlServer down or Detach that database ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191491.aspx)) before copying.

Answer (score 1):

Rather that copy the actual MDF, it's probably a better idea to backup the MDF using SQL Server's built in [BACKUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) command.

The suggestions to detach the database and then copy it are problematic because it takes your database offline.

Answer (score 0):

The server denies inteprocess access to data files. Once it has opened a data file no other process can open one too. That's why your function fails.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question 'how can [he] copy that db which is already in use' but instead just points out why his existing code fails.

Answer (score 0):

You should close all open connections to DB to access the DB file. But generally, you should not touch the database file. You'd better use SQL command to back up the database.

```
string backupCommandText = "BACKUP DATABASE [<YOUR_DB_NAME>]" +
   "TO  DISK = N'<BACKUP_PATH>' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, " + 
   "NAME = N'Web-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = backupCommandText ;
cmd.Connection = conn;  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer
But i got following Error:

"Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'dbSTK'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally."

I have Created database from VisualStudio IDE with default sqlserver instance (.\SQLEXPRESS)